# Can molten metal be suspended in air?

Tags: forces, metals, levitation

I wondered if magnets could be used to hold a drop of molten liquid metal in air (not for any particular reason just because it could be done), but was disappointed when a quick Google search showed the metal would lose its magnetic traits before it melted.

Are there any other forces that could be used to suspend a drop of molten liquid metal in air such as sound waves, high pressure air, electric currents, or anything else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will molten iron stick to a magnet?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/59280/)

Comment: @BrandonEnright but this question is phrased to include any metal, and would include suspending by paramagnetic or diamagnetic effect, analogous to liquid oxygen being suspended between the poles of a magnet.

Comment: This is used to measure the surface tension of liquid metals.

Comment: @DavePhD yeah the question is way too broadly worded if you allow for anything.  For example, your answer is "yes" and a series of links.

Comment: I added an explanation to the answer so it's not just "yes" anymore.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it is possible to magnetically levitate molten metal. This is not due to ferromagnetism however.  As seen in the below references, the metal sample is placed within a tapered conducting coil, which carries alternating electric current in the ~400kilohertz range.  This sets up a magnetic field gradient inside the coil and causes eddy currents in the sample. The applied magnetic field is excluded from the interior of the sample.  The sample experiences a force in the direction of decreasing magnetic field strength.

See the following for more information:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=intDuSJ2_PA

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6Zrnv4OtbU

http://www.google.com/patents/US2686864

http://www.google.com/patents/US2686865

http://www.cs.duke.edu/~reif/temp/MagneticLevitation/LevitationSuveys/Levitation%20in%20Physics.pdf

http://www.modlab.lv/publications/mmp2010/pdfs/015-020.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Molten glass is suspended (and spun) on air jets to form "pre-forms" for molding glass optics. I suspect that the same must be possible for metals.